# How can I determine how many AVX registers my processor has?

Tags: c++, cpu-registers, avx

Currently I'm developing function that counts integral using AVX registers. I want to know if there are enough of them on my computer. How can I find out that?

Comment: Do you want to determine it specifically for your computer, or any computer (at runtime or compile-time)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming a CPU with AVX at all (i.e. not Pentium/Celeron, even latest-generation):

32-bit mode always has 8 architectural YMM registers.  32-bit mode is mostly obsolete for high-performance computing.

64-bit mode has 16 YMM regs, or with AVX512VL, 32 if you include using EVEX-encoded 256-bit versions of instructions.

In either case, these are renamed onto a larger physical register file (PRF), avoiding write-after-write and write-after-read hazards.  https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/05/measuring-rob-capacity/ has some info about out-of-order execution window size being limited by PRF size, instead of by the ReOrder Buffer (ROB).

---

You could detect 64-bit mode with `#if defined(__x86_64__)` on most compilers, `#if defined(_M_X64)` on MSVC.

Compile-time detection of AVX is `__AVX__`, AVX512VL is `__AVX512VL__`.  (Mainstream CPUs with AVX512 have it, Xeon Phi (KNL / KNM) don't; only legacy SSE or AVX512 full-width ZMM.)  You may want to only do runtime detection of AVX instead of enabling it as a baseline for all your source files, though.

Comment: The macros just tests whether code will be able to compile. Further runtime testing is required or it won't work on some processors.

Comment: @ALX23z: Not if you compile with `-march=native` on every machine you're going to run it on.  But yeah, fair point that enabling AVX across the board isn't what everyone wants to do.  I separated the x86-64 detection from the AVX detection in my answer.